# How to compare two lists of objects in C#?

Tags: linq, list

Lets say I have a list of objects:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
}
```

now the data:

```
{0, "my", DateTime.Now}
{0, "List", DateTime.Now}
{0, "Data", DateTime.Now}
```

Now say I stripped this data from an XML or Excel document and I want to compare with what is in the database and Ignore data that already exists. I am using Entity Framework to handle this.

```
 public IEnumerable<MyObject> GetBy()
{
    return _context.MyObjects.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
}
```

I know if you want to get data from a list where it is different you use:

```
var myNewStuff = myStuff.Except(myDataBaseStuff);
```

But none of the ID properties will match so that won't work

How do I compare the two lists BASED on the Name AND StartDate values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement your own `IEqualityComparer` and use the overload of `Except` that takes it. Using Resharper, I generated this one:

```
public sealed class NameStartDateEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyObject>
{
    public bool Equals(MyObject x, MyObject y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
        return string.Equals(x.Name, y.Name) && x.StartDate.Equals(y.StartDate);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyObject obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((obj.Name != null ? obj.Name.GetHashCode() : 0)*397) ^ obj.StartDate.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the comparer only examines the `Name` and `StartDate` properties. You can of course change the comparer to your liking, like truncating the milliseconds off of the `StartDate` before comparing them. Then use it as such:

```
var myNewStuff = myStuff.Except(myDataBaseStuff, new NameStartDateEqualityComparer());
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking I was going to have to do. I was hoping there was some existing method I didn't know about that would handle it.